# Как распараллелить циклы?

Tags: потоки-данных, java, циклы

Помогите разобраться с тем, как можно распараллеливать циклы..   
Вот допустим у меня есть некоторый метод, который должен вызываться с разными входными параметрами в цикле. Результат записывается в массив.    
Каждая итерация цикла независима от других. Как распараллелить этот процесс?

И еще, как мне быть в такой ситуации:

```
 public class MainClass(){

  public void main(){

    Generator g = new Generator();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      ArrayList<String> res = g.funcion(i); // здесь все должно выполняться последовательно
      System.put.println(res.size());
    }
  }   
}   
public class Generator(){

  public function(int i){

    // Вот тут то и хотелось бы распараллелить выполнение метода function2
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    res.addAll(function2(i));
    res.addAll(function2(i*i));

  }

  public function2(int i){
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: В C# было бы так:

    public IEumberable<string> function(int i)
    {
        return new[] { i, i*i }.AsParallel().AsOrdered().Select(function2);
    }

С другой стороны, вы пишете в вопросе, что итерации независимы, а в коде, что цикл в `main` должен выполняться последовательно. Что из этого верно?

Comment: задал несколько вопросов:    
один - как разпараллелить цикл из независимых итераций    
второй на примере

Comment: @Stas0n: а, понял, это независимые вопросы. В .NET распараллелить [легко](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688.aspx), в Java должно быть тоже, ждём, пока подтянутся знатоки.

Comment: Зачем вы постоянно хотите что-то параллелить?

Comment: @VladD, очень красиво паралеллится на с++, аж глаз радует)    
Только у меня не плюсы, а java

Comment: @Stas0n: Так и @VladD предложил не плюсы, а c#. На плюсах циклы хорошо параллелятся при помощи OpenMP

Comment: @IronVbif, согласен... И, все-таки, OpenMP очень впечатляюще смотрится)

Answer (score 3):

Если каждая итерация цикла из main не зависит от других, то логичнее было бы запускать каждую итерацию в отдельном потоке (а не вызовы `function2`, как вы хотите). Тогда вам понадобится список результатов работы каждого потока и какой-нибудь пул потоков, отслеживающий, завершили ли они работу. После запуска всех потоков, основной поток будет засыпать, а когда все потоки отработают, пул его разбудит, он пройдётся по результатам, и выведет их на экран. Для хранения результатов работы потоков лучше использовать не простой `List`, а потокобезопасный. Такой можно получить либо при помощи [`Collections.synchronizedList(List<T> list)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)), либо при помощи [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html), либо заворачивая обращения к этому списку в synchronized-блок. В качестве пула потоков можно использовать [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). В [этой статье](http://javadissection.blogspot.com/2012/11/delegating-to-executors-the-management-of-threads.html) кратко описано, как им пользоваться. А ещё можно дождаться выхода Java 8, в которой всё это реализовано на уровне API.

Comment: @fori1ton, дело в том, что итерации в main зависят друг от друга, разбивать их в потоки невозможно.    
Вопрос качался того, как распараллелить метод function2() в методе function класса Generator.

Comment: Всё вышесказанное можно применить и для распараллеливания `function2`. Не совсем, кстати, понятно, хотите ли вы распараллелить вызовы `function2`, или что-то внутри неё. В первом случае сильного выигрыша не будет, ведь у вас всего два вызова. Во втором - зависит от того, что происходит в `function2`. Эффективнее всего параллелить циклы.

Comment: @fori1ton, выйгрыш будет) метод function2 съедает львиную долю времени работы программы...

Comment: @fori1ton если вызовы function2 можно делать независимо, то почему вы утверждаете, что итерации в main зависят друг от друга?

Answer (score 3):

1. Есть нечто вроде LinQ для Java - библиотека [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) с помощью ее можно обращаться с коллекциями как некими сущностями не прибегая к циклу по их внутренностям. Не уверен, что на выходе будет параллельное выполнение - это уже зависит от компилятора. Но синтаксически будет довольно красиво как в SQL.
2. Реальное распараллеливание можно сделать с помощью `Thread`'ов, но результат вам не понравится...

Comment: @Barmaley,
>но результат вам не понравится...
Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: @Stas0n синтаксически это выглядит не очень...

Answer (score 2):

Создай класс, который будет реализовать интерфейс Runnable

```
public class YourClass implements Runnable{
    private int myInt;

    public YourClass(int _myInt){
        myInt = _myInt;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        // Твой код
    }

}
```

А вместо

```
res.addAll(function2(i*i));
```

Напиши

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new YourClass(i));
thread.start();
```

Код из function2 перенеси в run()

Comment: @dimka3210, а без введения класса не получится как-нибудь?   
И как кстати сделать так, чтобы результат распараллеливания присваивался какой-либо одной переменной? Ну, т.е. как сделать так, чтобы function2(i) был одним ArrayList<String>, а function2(i) другим?

Comment: Результат распараллеливания я бы положил в HashMap

Comment: Логичней было бы юзать не Runnable, а Callable. Он умеет сам возвращать значения.

Answer (score 1):

как-то так:

```
public abstract class ThreadHelper {
    public static <T> void exec(Callable<T> ...callable) throws InterruptedException {
        // validate input
        if (null == callable || 0 == callable.length) {
            return;
        }

        List<Callable<T>> tasks = Arrays.asList(callable);

        // special for @IronVbif
        int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();                     
        // execute thread group
        ExecutorService threadpool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores*2);
        threadpool.invokeAll(tasks);
        threadpool.shutdown();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final List<Object> result = new LinkedList<Object>();

        // callable one
        Callable<Object> callable = new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 33; i < 77; i++) {
                    result.add(i);
                    Thread.sleep(15);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        Callable<Object> callable2 = new Callable<Object>() {
            @Override
            public Object call() throws Exception {
                for (int i = 97; i < 133; i++) {
                    result.add(String.valueOf((char)i));
                    Thread.sleep(25);
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        try {
            exec(callable, callable2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("failed: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**google**:

```
java parallel execution
```

Comment: Лучше вынести создание пула за пределы exec и задать ему размер сравнимый с количеством аппаратных тредов в процессоре. Потому что в такой код потенциально можно передать 1000000 объектов и вы запустите столько же потоков.